# How to make a fixed topbar in Foundation 6.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

In twitter bootstrap fixed class is used to make a fixed topbar, what is the equivalent way in Foundation 6.2?

Comment: You can use their sticky navigation, for more info see their [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sticky.html#sticky-navigation) about sticky navigation

Answer (score 1):

Zurb Foundation 6 simple sticky menu:

```
<div style="height:999px;">
   <div data-sticky-container>
      <div id="widemenu" class="top-bar" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" style="width:100%;height:50px;">
         <div class="top-bar-title menu-text"><a href="#">Title Here</a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script>$(document).foundation();</script>
```